# Compute $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \left(\sqrt{\left(x+\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\right) ^3} - \sqrt{x^3} \right) $

Tags: limits

Compute $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \left(\sqrt{\left(x+\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\right) ^3} - \sqrt{x^3} \right) $.
I tried multiplying by the conjugate and I get to an ugly expression. What should I do?

Comment: You need to multiply *and divide* by the conjugate.  But you don't need to evaluate the resulting ugly expression.  You just need to divide the numerator and denominator by the appropriate power of $x$, and *then* take the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you arrived at

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{(x+1/\sqrt x)^3}-\sqrt{x^3}&=\frac{3x^{3/2}+3+x^{-3/2}}{\sqrt{(x+1/\sqrt x)^3}+\sqrt{x^3}}\\\\
&=\frac{3x^{3/2}+3+x^{-3/2}}{x^{3/2}\left(1+\sqrt{(1+1/x^{3/2})^3}\right)}
\end{align}$$

Now let $x\to \infty$.  Can you finish now?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

hint :- it becomes very easy if you substitute $x = \frac{1}{t^2}$  where as $x \rightarrow \infty $ , $t \rightarrow 0$ ( precisely from right hand side)  this would simplify to easily solvable form using l'hopital or other techniques

Comment: this would make the rationalisation very easy

Answer (score 0):

Hello Taylor my old friend...

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{\left(x+\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\right) ^3} - \sqrt{x^3}
&=\left(x+x^{-1/2}\right) ^{3/2} - x^{3/2}\\
&=x^{3/2}\left(\left(1+x^{-3/2}\right) ^{3/2} - 1\right)\\
&=x^{3/2}\left(\left(1+\frac32x^{-3/2}+O(x^{-3})\right) - 1\right)\\
&=x^{3/2}\left(\frac32x^{-3/2}+O(x^{-3})\right)\\
&=\frac32+O(x^{-3/2})\\
\end{array}
$

Actually, of course,
it's the generalized binomial theorem,
but that doesn't scan as well.